# Table View Controller vs Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a program that has a list of information that when tapped it needs to take you a screen to get more information about that item. I don't know if I need to use a Table View Controller or a Navigation Controller.

What would you recommend and why? What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UINavigationController is a 'container' controller. Meaning, it houses other view controllers inside of it. So if you wanted a UITableviewController inside a UINavigationViewController you could make it as such:

```
[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yourTableView];
```

Then when you select the item from the table that you wish to show new information, you will 'push' a new view controller onto the the UINavigationController stack:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
```

This can be done inside the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

function of your UITableViewController. It will create the toolbars at the top for you, as well as the backwards navigation buttons that are expected.

[This link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10) is to the apple documentation that explains the types of view controllers, and it is definitely worth the read.

Comment: As already announced by Apple, it is worth noting iOS5 supports the creation of your own container view controllers, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both. A UITableViewController will display a list of items, and a UINavigationController will let you go to a secondary ("detail") screen.

Read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a table view controller inside a navigation controller. The table view controller would provide your list of items. Then you push a normal view controller, using the `UINavigationController` when you want to show more information.